# Has the python3.6 interpreter changed?

Tags: python, python-3.6, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

My debian python 2.7 and python 3.4 had normal up/down button command history. When I go into my newly built/installed python 3.6.3 the cursor physically moves to the line above instead. If this is correct behaviour how do I recall command history in the interpreter?

Comment: Did you build Python 3.6 yourself?  If so, can you instead try a prebuilt package for it, for example using Conda if your system package manager doesn't have it?  I wonder if your build did not detect `libreadline` correctly--I think that's what implements the missing behavior.  Maybe you didn't have `readline-dev` or similar installed when building Python?

Comment: The interactive interpreter in Python 3.6.0 (which I compiled myself) behaves as expected for me on a Debian derivative distro. Are you talking about IDLE?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using [`IDLE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) instead of [`REPL`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)? On `IDLE` default command history recall is `alt+p`.

Comment: configured with the following switches: `./configure --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --cc="gcc -fPIC" --enable-pic`. 

Readline dev headers were not installed though, so I presume I need to rebuild my python?

Comment: using repl, yes definitely.

Comment: If readline (incl. its interfaces, some distros do not want to trouble its users with being able to build their SW) were not installed as upi mention, autoconf would would configure your build w/o readline support (readline provides the "usual" behavior of interactive sessions).